# What's the most efficient way to filter a DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

... by checking whether a columns' value is in a `seq`.
Perhaps I'm not explaining it very well, I basically want this (to express it using regular SQL): `DF_Column IN seq`?

First I did it using a `broadcast var` (where I placed the seq), `UDF` (that did the checking) and `registerTempTable`.
The problem is that I didn't get to test it since I ran into a [known bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5281) that apparently only appears when using `registerTempTable` with *ScalaIDE*.

I ended up creating a new `DataFrame` out of `seq` and doing inner join with it (intersection), but I doubt that's the most performant way of accomplishing the task.

Thanks

**EDIT:** (in response to @YijieShen):
How to do `filter` based on whether elements of one `DataFrame`'s column are in another DF's column (like SQL `select * from A where login in (select username from B)`)?

E.g:
First DF:

```
login      count
login1     192  
login2     146  
login3     72
```

Second DF:

```
username
login2
login3
login4
```

The result:

```
login      count
login2     146  
login3     72
```

**Attempts:**
***EDIT-2:** I think, now that the bug is fixed, these should work. **END EDIT-2***

```
ordered.select("login").filter($"login".contains(empLogins("username")))
```

and

```
ordered.select("login").filter($"login" in empLogins("username"))
```

which both throw `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException`, respectively:

```
resolved attribute(s) username#10 missing from login#8 in operator 
!Filter Contains(login#8, username#10);
```

and

```
resolved attribute(s) username#10 missing from login#8 in operator 
!Filter login#8 IN (username#10);
```

Comment: What's the size of the `Seq` roughly?

Comment: Small, currently 100 elements, and it should never go above 10k.

Comment: How about use the DSL of dataFrame instead of sql?

Comment: @MarkoBonaci, which version of spark are you using? Does [spark-5281] also affect your version? or just because you are using ScalaIDE that causes your first attempt fail?

Comment: @MarkoBonaci, please check if the answer i posted below works for you.

Comment: can you not just do RDD intersect(or join) on the 2 data frames?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You should broadcast a `Set`, instead of an `Array`, much faster searches than linear.
2. You can make Eclipse run your Spark application. Here's how:

As pointed out on the mailing list, spark-sql assumes its classes are loaded by the primordial classloader. That's not the case in Eclipse, were the Java and Scala library are loaded as part of the boot classpath, while the user code and its dependencies are in another one. You can easily fix that in the launch configuration dialog:

- remove Scala Library and Scala Compiler from the "Bootstrap" entries
- add (as external jars) `scala-reflect`, `scala-library` and `scala-compiler` to the user entry.

The dialog should look like this:

[image]

> Edit: The [Spark bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5281) was fixed and this workaround is no longer necessary (since v. 1.4.0)

Answer (score 16):

My code *(following the description of your first method)* runs normally in `Spark 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT` on these two configurations:

- `Intellij IDEA's test`
- `Spark Standalone cluster` with 8 nodes (1 master, 7 worker)

Please check if any differences exists

```scala
val bc = sc.broadcast(Array[String]("login3", "login4"))
val x = Array(("login1", 192), ("login2", 146), ("login3", 72))
val xdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(x).toDF("name", "cnt")

val func: (String => Boolean) = (arg: String) => bc.value.contains(arg)
val sqlfunc = udf(func)
val filtered = xdf.filter(sqlfunc(col("name")))

xdf.show()
filtered.show()
```

**Output**

> name   cnt 
>   login1 192 
>   login2 146 
>   login3 72
>
> name   cnt
>   login3 72

Comment: I'm using 1.3.1. I can also run it in all environments except ScalaIDE. I've just tried your code and [the same bug](https://gist.github.com/mbonaci/7c4a7160e45654840b33) happens (the same code is run in the background, as when using sql expresson). In IDEA, it runs fine. So do we conclude that, given the bug, the only possible option in ScalaIDE is to do inner join? Or you have some alternative ideas?

Comment: @MarkoBonaci, or you could just move to IDEA and forget about the error :)

Comment: :) Well, this is a part of an example in a book I'm working on. But, I was just thinking that maybe this wasn't such a bad thing after all. It could be like a real-life situation that you're forced to deal with a road block and find an alternate solution. From that standpoint, it's not even that important that the algorithm does not suck (I guess, alternatives must always suck, even just a little bit :) Would you mind if you became one of the characters in the book (like a supporting actor - a good samaritan from the SO)? BTW, it's Spark in Action for Manning.

Comment: @MarkoBonaci, just thinking broadcast variable & udf fits your requirements better, although workaround is a must sometimes. No, I don't mind :)

Comment: @YijieShen I am getting an error while performing udf inside filter ..like found ColName required String ` val DS_in = DS_In.filter($"cid" === 2).join(DS_B,Seq("cid","aid"),"inner").filter(compareUsage($"usagetype"))` my udf `val compareUsage: (String => Boolean) = (str: String) =>
    if (str == "" || str == null) {
      true
    } else if ((str.toString().toUpperCase().contains("Acitve")) || (str.toString().toUpperCase() contains ("USAGE"))) true else false
 ` Can you tell me where its is going wrong