# How do I remove rows of an RDD whose key is not in another RDD?

Tags: join, apache-spark, rdd

Let's say I have a PairRDD, students (id, name). I would like to only keep rows where id is in another RDD, activeStudents (id).

The solution I have is to create a PairDD from activeStudents, (id, id), and the do a join with students.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Thats a pretty good solution to start with. If active students is small enough you could collect the ids as a map and then filter with the id presence (this avoids having to a do a shuffle).

Answer (score 0):

Much like you thought, you can do an outer join if both RDDs contain keys and values.

```
val students: RDD[(Long, String)]
val activeStudents: RDD[Long]
val activeMap: RDD[(Long, Unit)] = activeStudents.map(_ -> ())
val activeWithName: RDD[(Long, String)] =
  students.leftOuterJoin(activeMap).flatMapValues {
    case (name, Some(())) => Some(name)
    case (name, None) => None
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to join those two data sets then you should definitely avoid it.
I had a similar problem recently and I successfully solved it using a broadcasted Set, which I used in UDF to check whether each RDD row (rather value from one of its columns) is in that Set. That UDF is than used as the basis for the filter transformation.

More here: [whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-filter-a-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796928/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-filter-a-dataframe).

Hope this helps. Ask if it's not clear.