# How to Subset a Spark Dataframe Using Another Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**Update 8/16/2015**
It turns out something went wrong with the select statement to exclude the duplicate columns after join.
I was using the old syntax that returns both key columns from the two source table and the select statement for some reasons crashes scala. I didn't save the error message. If someone is interested in it, I will replicate the error and post it later this week.

```
A.join(B, A("ID")===B("ID")).select("ID","Score")
```

Spark 1.4.1 allows the below syntax to specify the key variable in the join without producing duplicate columns-

```
A.join(B, "ID")
```

---

I am a Spark newbie and trying to subset a data frame using a list that stores in another data frame. I was wondering if there's something in Spark Dataframe Api or Rdd that is similar to SQL IN operator in Spark so I can write a query like this-

```
SparkContext.sql(select * from A where A.ID in (select distinct ID from B))
```

I have try dataframe API inner join but it failed the second time I subset using the same list probably because my dataframes are too large. 
I found a post that may answer my question but I don't quite understand what the post suggested - [What's the most efficient way to filter a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796928/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-filter-a-dataframe)

I would appreciate any suggestions either on Spark Dataframe API or RDD. Thank you!

### A

> ID Score
>   001 95
>   002 93
>   003 80
>   004 54
>   002 67
>   008 56

### B

> ID
>   002
>   004
>   005

Comment: Please, try o provide details when ask questions. What is the size of A and B? What is the expected number/fraction of common elements. What is the source of the failure when you use join? What kind of resources do you have at your disposal?

Comment: Please provide what have you tried and what error messages did you get.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I have updated the above post. I apologize for not providing enough details for the question.

Comment: @SHY. can you post an answer to the question (and accept it) to make it clear that you solved the issue?